# How to add a javascript function call to a HyperLink field in a list?

Tags: list-item

Normally when you are writing regular HTML, you can create a link that will execute a JavaScript function.

```
<a href="javascript:myFunction();">click me</a>
```

However, in a SP List that is using a Hyperlink field, you can not use this format;  Sharepoint doesn't recognize this as a valid URL.

I have a list of links that get shown on the page.  The links are stored in the list and retrieved on the page.  Right now, I have to add separate code after the page loads to convert these links to run the javascript calls.  This seems like a extra effort for something that seems like it should just work.

Is there any way to get around this limitation? Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: Microsoft disabled it because it would allow script-injection... Which you can  do with [Calculated Columns](http://www.viewmaster365.com/index.html#/How)... BUT.. Calculated Columns can't reference Hyperlink fields, so you would have to convert them to  Single Line of Text

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Thank you for your answer.  That explains why it doesn't work.